# IE cannot access Facebook FQL result

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have an FQL query which is run on client side with JQuery. It works fine and returns a result in Chrome, but in IE I cannot get a result. The JQuery code is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: fb_url,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function( msg ) {...});
```

When I write the value of fb_url (which is below) manually in address bar, Chrome gets the JSON result, however IE gives "Unable to download FQL from graph.facebook.com" error.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...&access_token=...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataType is incorrect for a cross-domain scenario.  Specify 'jsonp' and you should be able to get the information in IE.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: fb_url,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(function( msg ) {...});
```